# iPhone: NSComparisonResult and NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch issue Scandinavian alphabets

Tags: iphone

I use NSComparisonResult for searching through my array, but when I use NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch, it cant find immediately Scandinavian alphabets like å æ ø, but it can find such alphabets as á etc. When I remove NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch in options: , then my search bar can find å æ ø immediately, but ignore à and such.

Is there any solution to this?

EDIT 15 august:
I believe using NSScanner (though I have no experience with this) in if logic for detecting å æ ø in searchstring, if they exist, then no nsdiactricinsensitivesearch. If no å æ ø in searchstring, then include nsdiactricinsensitivesearch in nscomparisonresult. I will try to implement this soon and give feedback if this works or not.

---

My codes:

```
NSComparisonResult result;
         NSString *setext = searchText;
         NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:setext];
         NSString *a = @"å";
         while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO)
         {
              if ( [scanner scanString:a intoString:NULL])
              {
             [scanner scanUpToString:a intoString: NULL];
             result = [mystr compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch) 
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];              

              }
              else 
              {
              result = [mystr compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) 
                range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
        }

    }
```

But it is a bit slower than my modification of JohnBrighton´s solution:

```
        NSComparisonResult result;
        NSString *string = searchText;
        NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"æ"];
        NSRange range2 = [string rangeOfString:@"ø"];
        NSRange range3 = [string rangeOfString:@"å"];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound || range2.location != NSNotFound || range3.location != NSNotFound ) 

//if ((range.location != NSNotFound)  | (range2.location != NSNotFound ) | (range3.location != NSNotFound ) ) {


{
            result = [mystr compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch) 
                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];       
        }   
        else {
            result = [mystr compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) 
                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
        }
```

---

Does anyone know whats the difference between || and | in if logic?

Comment: Please just edit your question in the future to provide additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Does anyone know whats the difference between || and | in if logic?*

You can't use "|" in that case, as it's a bitwise OR operator. "||" is a boolean logical operator, which doesn't work with bits as the bitwise OR.

Comment: Thanks. When do I use the former symbol? Ok, I will use the latter symbol for if logic.

Comment: Typically, you use bitwise operators when working with flags, for example. Take a look at http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html - it's a thorough and interesting article every programmer should at least read.